# Flow exposed in external website using Lightning out - Not Rendering, no error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, visual-workflow, lightning-out, cors

### What I did

Aura Component

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Hello world from Component');
        var flow = cmp.find("flowData");
        flow.startFlow("Self_Registration");
    }
})
```

Aura App

```
<aura:application access="Global" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:externalLeadGenerator"/>
</aura:application>
```

Controller

```
({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Hello world from App');
    }
})
```

My website (running WordPress) is whitelisted in CORS.

This is an HTML code embedded on my page.

```
<!-- wp:html -->
<script src="https://ajfmo-developer-edition.na174.force.com/pmc/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:leadGeneratorApp",    // name of the Lightning app
        function() {                  // Callback once framework and app loaded
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:externalLeadGenerator", // top-level component of your app
                { },                  // attributes to set on the component when created
                "lightningLocator",   // the DOM location to insert the component
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log('Hi from callback');// callback when component is created and active on the page
                }
            );
        }, 'https://ajfmo-developer-edition.na174.force.com/pmc'  // Community endpoint
    );
</script>
<!-- /wp:html -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<div id="lightningLocator">
<p>Something</p>
</div>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

This is the result.

[image]

---

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no init handler in component code.
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>

Comment: wow, I totally missed that, you can post it as an answer please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no **init handler** in the component code.

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that the site guest user for your community endpoint has the right permissions to run the flow? There might be no errors starting the Lightning-out container but the guest user may be running into an issue accessing the flow. More details about site guest users and flow access can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_flow_guestuser.htm&type=5).

You could probably test this by adding the flow into a publically accessible community and accessing it as the site guest user. I believe the guest user would still need the "Run Flow" permission even if the flow lives in a Salesforce community.